# Raspbmc filtering connections from outside LAN

Tags: networking, raspbmc

I'm having a problem connecting to Raspbmc through my NAT firewall... My setup is like this :

```
raspbmc     <--LAN--> (eth1) router (eth0)  <--WAN--> work
192.168.1.3           192.168.1.2   5.6.7.8           1.2.3.4
```

I have forwarded the ports, and can confirm via `tcpdump` that the SYN packets are arriving at the Pi. However userspace never receives them! I have confirmed this using 3 different applications (pyroTorrent, XBMC web interface, and `nc`), and all give no response to the packet shown in `tcpdump`.

It works fine from the LAN, and I can get it to work by adding the following to my router's `iptables` config, but this is really ugly and I would like to get it to work without resorting to such manipulation :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 5555 -j MASQUERADE
```

I checked and the `rp_filter` is set to 0 for all interfaces on the Pi. Also, `iptables` is empty and has default policy ACCEPT for everything. Did I miss something specific to Raspbmc/Raspbian?

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers :)

Thomas

Here is the relevant output of `iptables-save` on the router :

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Feb 20 14:20:23 2013
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6829322:4371711949]
:INPUT ACCEPT [11442:1053089]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6817880:4370658860]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7244:653426]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [6825030:4371216486]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 20 14:20:23 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Feb 20 14:20:23 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2834:249851]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1124:63804]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [78:5781]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:5555
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb 20 14:20:23 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Feb 20 14:20:23 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [3875:330500]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6557:589075]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.4/32 -d 192.168.1.3/32 -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

And here is the `tcpdump` showing no reply from WAN, but successful transaction from LAN :

```
pi@raspbmc:~/pyrotorrent$ netstat -alpn|grep python
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7917/python

pi@raspbmc:~/pyrotorrent$ sudo tcpdump -vv 'port 5555'
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
14:36:56.038955 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22881, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.2.3.4.26741 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x038d (correct), seq 83867849, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:36:56.286900 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22895, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.2.3.4.42720 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x4dba (correct), seq 534844751, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:36:59.044256 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22922, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.2.3.4.26741 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x038d (correct), seq 83867849, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:36:59.278972 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22923, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    1.2.3.4.42720 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x4dba (correct), seq 534844751, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:37:05.040700 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22942, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    1.2.3.4.26741 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x179c (correct), seq 83867849, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:37:05.280175 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 112, id 22943, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    1.2.3.4.42720 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x61c9 (correct), seq 534844751, win 8192, options [mss 1340,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
14:37:12.148221 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15015, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.1.2.53754 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [S], cksum 0x92c6 (correct), seq 4011566171, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 16031484 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
14:37:12.148569 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.1.3.5555 > 192.168.1.2.53754: Flags [S.], cksum 0x8384 (incorrect -> 0xa57e), seq 1622032073, ack 4011566172, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 7482252 ecr 16031484,nop,wscale 6], length 0
14:37:12.149062 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15016, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.2.53754 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [.], cksum 0x0c23 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 183, options [nop,nop,TS val 16031484 ecr7482252], length 0
14:37:12.149450 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15017, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 161)
    192.168.1.2.53754 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [P.], cksum 0x75ee (correct), seq 1:110, ack 1, win 183, options [nop,nop,TS val 16031484 ecr 7482252], length 109
14:37:12.149615 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5446, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.3.5555 > 192.168.1.2.53754: Flags [.], cksum 0x837c (incorrect -> 0x0b8a), seq 1, ack 110, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 7482252 ecr 16031484], length 0
14:37:12.574406 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15018, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.2.53754 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [F.], cksum 0x0b8a (correct), seq 110, ack 1, win 183, options [nop,nop,TS val 16031527ecr 7482252], length 0
14:37:12.604953 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5447, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.1.3.5555 > 192.168.1.2.53754: Flags [.], cksum 0x837c (incorrect -> 0x0b30), seq 1, ack 111, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 7482298 ecr 16031527], length 0
14:37:13.080329 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 5448, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 69)
    192.168.1.3.5555 > 192.168.1.2.53754: Flags [P.], cksum 0x838d (incorrect -> 0x4b23), seq 1:18, ack 111, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 7482345 ecr 16031527], length 17
14:37:13.080861 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    192.168.1.2.53754 > 192.168.1.3.5555: Flags [R], cksum 0xb0f6 (correct), seq 4011566282, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: Huumm, i am not a network specialist...but i am very interested by any answer. I only can confirm with the final version of Raspbmc i am not able to connect to my nGinx Web Server from Internet. And this was worrking on the RC 4 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to people exposing SSH without changing the default password, I added some basic rules that restrict network access to LAN only. In a couple of days there'll be an option to disable these from Raspbmc's XBMC settings plugin, but for now, you can see this thread for advice

http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6726

Cheers

Comment: Ah thanks... I only checked with `iptables-save` which returned blank, but now with `iptables -L` I see the rules.